# RVM Install bash script does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

Trying to install RVM on Ubuntu 11.04 with no joy.
I have installed Curl 7.22.0

When I run:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

or

```
bash < <(curl -sk https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

from terminal, nothing happens, so if anybody has any suggestions

Comment: Have you tried downloading the script directly from... https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm and running that?

Comment: @Lloyd I haven't tried downloading the script directly as RVM uses curl ongoing, so if i skip this issue now I'm be afraid of it rearing its head in the future.

Comment: @mxmissile no, no error msg at all, no delay, just gives me a new prompt

Comment: @RishavRastogi Yes I have curl 7.22.0 installed

Comment: What happens when you hit `https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm` with a browser on the same machine?

Comment: I have the same problem here... Have you try accessing https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm with cURL (without the -s option)? I get a connection timeout error. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -x
```

I have personally verified this on RVM's testing cluster which tests against 4 different OSs as well as on OS X Lion. It works perfectly as does the multi-user installation. So something is going on in your environment on that machine. The `-x` will cause bash to output each command as its executing it. Also, you can do

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io -o rvm-installer ; chmod +x rvm-installer ; ./rvm-installer
```

as detailed on the https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ page, just removing the --version x.x.x portion of the listed command there. This is not an issue, this is our default response when someone's environment is acting up. There's nothing wrong with the RVM installer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

`sudo apt-get install git curl -y`

installed the version of curl that don't support ssl, so you need to uninstall it using

`sudo apt-get remove curl`

then install curl by downloading the latest package from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/curl (for natty), use this link [curl_7.21.3.orig.tar.gz],

`tar -xvzf curl_7.21.3.orig.tar.gz`

`cd curl_7.21.3`

`./configure && make`

check for errors, and if all fine type

`sudo make install`

now ssl is working, so you can install rvm simply using

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash`